Extremals of $\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1+(y')^2}}{y}\;dt$
Find extremals solution of
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1 + \left(y'\right)^2}}{y}{\rm d}t\quad
\mbox{for}\quad y\left(0\right) = 0,\ y\left(1\right) = \sqrt{3}
$$

My progress:

I have tried to use the Euler-Lagrange Equation and Beltrami's Identity.
The Euler-Lagrange Method gives me such a complicated equation.
Meanwhile, using Beltrami's Identity gives us
$$
C = y^{2}\left[1 + \left(y'\right)^{2}\right]
$$
and I don't know how to solve this differential equation.


I think the answer is $r=4\cos\theta$

How do differential equations relate to polar forms?

Your Beltrami equation is a separable first order ODE. I think you'll get multiple solutions for $y$ because of the squares.

Also note that $y^2(1 + (y')^2) \geq 0$ so that you can replace the constant $C$ with $C^2$.

I still didn't know how to use separable. So far I know if we have $dy/dx = f(x)g(y) \iff dy/g(y) = f(x) ; dx$ we can do this method.

Finally, I found it, as @MathsMatador mention.

You should write your solution as an answer and mark it correct

Try $y'=\tan p$ and get $y=y(p)$, $t=t(p)$.
